# Persist logged in user with angularfire2 using cookies

Tags: cookies, angular, firebase, firebase-authentication, angularfire2

I'm using a simple custom authentication with angularfire2 and the authentication service from Firebase.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFire } from 'angularfire2';
import { Cookie } from 'ng2-cookies';

@Injectable()
export class GlobalMenuService {

    loggedIn: boolean = false;

    constructor(private af: AngularFire) { }

    login(email: string, password: string) {
        this.af.auth.login({
            email: email,
            password: password
        })
            .then((success) => {
                this.loggedIn = true;
            });
    }

    logout() {
        this.af.auth.logout();
        this.loggedIn = false;
    }
}
```

Is there a way to save some data in a cookie (token, uid, email or something) to restore the session, i.e. each time the user returns to the app re-login him without him having to write the credentials ?

Comment: Firebase handles automatically the session. If you are using Firebase v3 the token will refresh without expiring

Comment: Hello, it doesn't seem to be that way and I'm using the latest release 3.1.0. As you can see I'm injecting an instance of AngularFire in the constructor and af.auth.getAuth() is always null when I start the application.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use [`auth.subscribe()`](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/issues/137). This function will be called any time there's a change in the authentication state.

```
this.af.auth.subscribe(user => {
  if (user) {
    // User is signed in.
    ... do other stuff
  } else {
    // No user is signed in.
    ... do other stuff
  }
});
```

If you are already logged in when you open your app, or you call `signInWithEmailAndPassword`, this function will be called and `auth` will contain your logged user data.

Comment: I do not have a direct reference to firebase since I have my app configured to use the AngularFire library. Do you perhaps know if the library supports the suggested method or has something identical to it since I can't seem to find it?

Comment: You are right, I've updated my answer with some info found [here](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/5-user-authentication.md) Does this solve your issue? :)

Comment: I see, the authentication state was persistent all along I was just calling the wrong method. Thanks for helping me out solve my problem but also thanks for being nice & polite since this was my first post I thought I was going to get bashed because 'text isn't formatted correctly' or 'information is not sufficient' or X reason :)).

Comment: Please [don't post identical answers to multiple questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/104227). Post one good answer, then vote/flag to close the other questions as duplicates. If the question is not a duplicate, *tailor your answers to the question*.